# Service worker fetch does not make network request

Tags: service-worker

Extremely simple case. I'm trying to do network-first caching, since the content is mutable. However, the service worker seems to serve from the disk cache instead of the network. It doesn't even seem to check with the server for updates (in Chromium). See attached screenshot.

Here is my page:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      function printFile() {
        fetch('file.txt').then(resp => resp.text()).then(x => console.log(x));
      }

      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
          .then(function(reg) {
            // registration worked
            console.log('Registration succeeded. Scope is ' + reg.scope);

            navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(printFile);
          }).catch(function(error) {
            // registration failed
            console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
          });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and service worker:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  console.log('Fetching ' + event.request.url);
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request)
  );
});
```

How can I force my service worker to make a request to the server to fetch a fresh copy of `file.txt`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ah, apparently the fetch goes through the regular browse cache first. Solution to this was posted in [Jaffa's excellent guide](https://jakearchibald.com/2016/caching-best-practices/#a-service-worker-can-extend-the-life-of-these-bugs)